# derived query in crm plugin

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, query-expressions

Is there a way I can write a derived query in for a CRM Plugin?
Newbie on CRM dev here.

Query looks like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table1 
WHERE table1.ID1 = XXXX AND table1.ID2 NOT IN (
    SELECT table2.ID1
    FROM table2 
    WHERE table2.ID2 = XXXX)
```

Writing the code using a queryexpression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately these kind of complex sql queries cannot be achieved via fetchxml or queryexpression queries. Especially like [Subqueries](https://ideas.dynamics.com/ideas/dynamics-crm/782619), Not In scenarios.

Probably you need multiple resultset (EntityCollection), one for table1 & another one for table2, then transversing through it.

Another choice is [LINQ queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509026.aspx), you can try.

On a side note, you can [vote this idea](https://ideas.dynamics.com/ideas/dynamics-crm/675226) to improve the querying ability.

Comment: This was the approach I took. There's probably an approach for it but this was the quickest way for me to proceed, given time constraints. It just felt like the long road though...

Answer (score 0):

If you truly are using CRM 2011, last time I checked, this is not possible, newer versions (2013+) you can perform this type of query.
Please see this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn481591.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

```cs
var qe = new QueryExpression("table1");

var link = qe.AddLink("table2", "id2", "id1", JoinOperator.LeftOuter);
link.LinkCriteria.AddCondition("id2", ConditionOperator.Equal "XXXX")
link.EntityAlias = "notIn";

qe.Criteria = new FilterExpression();
qe.Criteria.AddCondition("id1", ConditionOperator.Equal, "XXXX");
qe.Criteria.AddCondition("notIn", "id1", ConditionOperator.Null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this expression with **LINQ for CRM**:

```
OrganizationServiceContext oservice = new OrganizationServiceContext(service);

using (oservice)
{
    var query = (from table1 in oservice.CreateQuery("new_table1")
                 join table2 in oservice.CreateQuery("new_table2") on table1["new_table1id"]
                     equals table2["new_table2id"]
                 where
                     table1.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("new_id1") 
                     == new Guid("the equal guid or field")
                 where
                     table2.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("new_id2").Id
                     != table1.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("new_id1").Id
                     && table2.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("new_id2").Id 
                     == new Guid("the not equal guid or field")
                 select table1).ToList();
}
```

This is another way to QueryExpression. `oservice.CreateQuery("new_table1")` is the name of your entity in CRM

This works on CRM 2011 too.